# Unable to use new Vagrant install - Error while connecting to libvirt

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

Regardless if I have a Vagrant file or if one doesn't exist and I create my own with `vagrant init` (which works btw) I get an error when trying to do this:

```
vagrant up
```

The error is:

```
1: from /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.0.43/lib/vagrant-libvirt/driver.rb:40:in `connection'
/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/vagrant-libvirt-0.0.43/lib/vagrant-libvirt/driver.rb:43:in `rescue in connection': Error while connecting to libvirt: 
Error making a connection to libvirt URI qemu:///system?no_verify=1&keyfile=/home/michael/.ssh/id_rsa: (VagrantPlugins::ProviderLibvirt::Errors::FogLibvirtConnectionError)
Call to virConnectOpen failed: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
Error while connecting to libvirt: Error making a connection to libvirt URI qemu:///system?no_verify=1&keyfile=/home/michael/.ssh/id_rsa:
Call to virConnectOpen failed: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory
```

This is on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 5):

Two things are needed:

1. You need to specifiy a provider
2. That provider needs to be setup

For 2 (setting up the provider) you can do (for example)

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Then, for 1 (setting up the box from them)

```
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

Comment: FWIW on my MacBook this worked (I already had virtualbox but the `--provider virtualbox` did it).  For the record my error was `Error while connecting to Libvirt: Error making a connection to libvirt URI qemu:///system:
Call to virConnectOpen failed: Failed to connect socket to '/usr/local/var/run/libvirt/virtqemud-sock': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that libvirt provider is missed. If you want to use libvirt as the provider, please install it with:

```
sudo apt install qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system bridge-utils
```

and then, with the default libvirt configuration, the vagrant needs the privilege to create a kvm machine:

```
sudo vagrant up
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

Then if still not good. check vagrant and virtualbox version compatibility

Answer (score 0):

For VMWARE workstation, follow the installation instructions [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/vmware/installation).

Then run `vagrant up --provider vmware_desktop`