# Error while starting Vagrant Virtual Machine

Tags: bash, ssh, vagrant, virtual-machine

I am using the vagrant VM and I have an environment set up using the following command:

```
mkdir Vagrant
cd Vagrant
vagrant init ubuntu/trusty/64
```

When I use `vagrant up` command it displays an error like :

```
Error while connecting to libvirt: Error making a connection to libvirt URI qemu:///system?no_verify=1&keyfile=/home/shashi/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

Call to virConnectOpen failed: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory

Comment: The question exists twice, please check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953554/unable-to-use-new-vagrant-install-error-while-connecting-to-libvirt)